# How to return all the duplicated objects with same values in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

is there a clever way to get all objects with same value?

```
[
  { name: 'a' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'b' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'c' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'd' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'e' , value: '12345'},
  { name: 'f' , value: '123456'}
]
```

the ideal result is:

```
[
  { name: 'a' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'b' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'c' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'd' , value: '1234'}
]
```

I am thinking to count all the occurance of values, but that seems not a good way.

Appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a `Map` and filter the array by the value of the map.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'a' , value: '123' }, { name: 'b' , value: '123' }, { name: 'c' , value: '1234' }, { name: 'd' , value: '1234' }, { name: 'e' , value: '12345' }, { name: 'f' , value: '123456' }],
    counts = array.reduce((m, { value }) => m.set(value, m.has(value)), new Map),
    result = array.filter(({ value }) => counts.get(value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like ur idea with the very new features in es6. it works like a charm! appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a sort sort algorithms, and then maybe a filter function.

hope this helps you .

you can sort the code by doing this :

```
let data = [
  { name: 'a' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'b' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'c' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'd' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'e' , value: '12345'},
  { name: 'f' , value: '123456'}
];

let cleanData = data.sort((a, b) = >{
    return a.value > b.value;
});

cleanData.filter((data) => data.value === 'requestedValue');
```

I am not sure about efficiency but this allow you to get the result you want.
By the way you can simply skip the ordering phase i did.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest algorithm, in my opinion, is to create map with values and filter by it. So yes, basically you will count all value occurrences.

Here the example:

```
const valuesMap = {}
const input = [
  { name: 'a' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'b' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'c' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'd' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'e' , value: '12345'},
  { name: 'f' , value: '123456'}
]

input.forEach(item => {
    if (!valuesMap[item.value]) {
         valuesMap[item.value] = 1
    } else {
         valuesMap[item.value] += 1
    }
})

const output = input.filter(item => {
     return valuesMap[item.value] > 1
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution use reduce with impurity(No need map again.)

```
const data = [
  { name: 'a' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'b' , value: '123'},
  { name: 'c' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'd' , value: '1234'},
  { name: 'e' , value: '12345'},
  { name: 'f' , value: '123456'}
]
const final = []
const counter = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((x, i) => {
    if(!x[i.value]) x[i.value] = 0
    x[i.value]++
    if(x[i.value] > 2) final.push(i)
    if(x[i.value] > 1) final.push(i, i)
    return x;
  }, {})
}
counter(data)
console.log(final)
```